# Network monitor by Process

Tags: networking, monitoring

Is there anything that allows me to monitor network usage by process for longer time (1 day +-). I know nethogs but it only shows current process and I need longer period to be monitored and probably logged to some file.

Also found vnstat to be nice, but only monitors total network usage...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Network Monitoring Solutions

1. [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/)
2. [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)
3. `lsof -i`
4. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
5. [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/)
6. [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)
7. [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

And [slurm](https://github.com/mattthias/slurm) is sexy for total bandwidth on an interface.

Comment: iftop will crash if left open for too long, just thought I'd mention that. I had issues with wireshark crashing when left open too long also.

Answer (score 1):

iptables can monitor network usage by port. assuming your application only uses a certain port, then this is a possibility

A quick google found this - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configuring-ip-traffic-accounting/

That should give you a pointer at least